# Setting parameters to a StaticResource

Tags: c#, wpf

I was wondering how can I pass a parameter to a StaticResource?

I want to enhance my LoanViewModel constructor to take a string.

```
public void LoanViewModel(string stringParameter)
{}
```

At the moment I'm setting the ItemsSource collection to my GridViewComboBoxColumn because of a known telerik bug.

```
<Telerik:GridViewComboBoxColumn
    ItemsSource="{Binding Statuses, Mode=TwoWay, Source={StaticResource LoanViewModel} />
```

Is there a way to pass a parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try to use property to control behavior. Working around constructor in XAML is little difficult. Or need to use markup extensions. below are some links.

[Static resource constructor with parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10349209/static-resource-constructor-with-parameters)